# Nested array of structs - how do i properly assign a value to struct members?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, variable-assignment

I have

```
struct Voice {
  static byte mode;
  //Some other stuff
};

byte Voice::mode{};   //Static member defined outside of struct declaration
```

and

```
struct DataPacket {
    DataPacket() : sequencer{}, voice{}, tempdata{} {};
    
    Sequencer sequencer;
    Voice voice[4];
    Tempdata tempdata;
};
```

I want to assign **one** of the voice struct members in the array with a variable value like this:

```
DataPacket assignVoiceValues(const InputPacket &inputPacket,
                             DataPacket &dataPacket,
                             const byte &voiceNumber) {
  dataPacket.voice[voiceNumber].mode = (byte) inputPacket.finalPotvalue[0];

  //Other code
}
```

Even though this compiles, when i test the code **all** of the four structs members `mode` in the `voice[]` array are simultaneously assigned with `inputPacket.finalPotvalue[0]`. There is no code for assigning values to `dataPacket.voice[voiceNumber].mode` elsewhere that could possibly interfere.

I have no idea why this is happening. What am i missing, and what is the proper syntax for making it work as intended?

(I know vectors generally are recommended over arrays, but the code is intended for an arduino board with limited memory).

Comment: Please provide a [mre], ideally one which does not require horizontal scrolling.

Comment: It happens because you made the member static. Why did you make it static?

Comment: On a side note, passing a `byte` (or any other primitive type) by const reference is a pessimization. Pass them by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have define mode as `static byte mode;`... So there's space allocated for exactly one of them in the entire program.

Perhaps `mode` should not be marked as `static`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you declare variable "mode" static it is bound to your class (which is single), not to instances of your class (you can create a lot of instances).

To fix the problem just remove static from description of your variable

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static